# Thunderbird extensions API - how to get message that's being replied to?

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-webextensions

I'm writing a Thunderbird extension that is currently able to trigger when a compose window is created (by listening to when a new tab is created, and then checking the contents of that tab for ComposeDetails). However, what I need is to know if the user is replying to another message, and if so, what other message they're replying to. That information isn't in the ComposeDetails, and I can't figure out how to find it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Thunderbird 88 will support it. The [`ComposeDetails`](https://thunderbird-webextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/compose.html#composedetails) are getting a new attribute `type`:

> `[type]` (*string*) – [Added in TB 88]
>
> Read-only. The type of the message being composed, depending on how the compose window was opened by the user.
>
> Supported values:
>
> - `draft`
> - `new`
> - `reply`
> - `forward`

I have no solution to suggest for older versions.